# Cache load Method call in constructor to set timer, is it bad approach?

Tags: c#, class, caching, constructor

In a C# project I have called a cache load method in constructor to set a timer. Is it a bad idea?

```
      public MyConstructor()
            {
                cacheDataManager = new MemoryCacheManager();

                var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
                           e => LoadMyCacheData(),
                          null,
                          TimeSpan.Zero,
                         TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
            }

//cache data method LoadMyCacheData
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have 2 wrong .
1- if you initialize cache in public constructor , when you create new instance from class your cache loaded . for resolve this problem you must be create static constructor

```
static MyConstructor()
            {
                cacheDataManager = new MemoryCacheManager();

                var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
                           e => LoadMyCacheData(),
                          null,
                          TimeSpan.Zero,
                         TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
            }
```

2- in your solution cache is a class level and this concept is far caching concept

```
 public class MyConstructor
    {
        public void Do()
        {
            MemoryCacheManager.Instance.myObject.ToString();
        }
    }

    public class MemoryCacheManager
    {
        private MemoryCacheManager()
        {
            myObject = new object();
        }

        private static MemoryCacheManager _cacheManager;

        public static MemoryCacheManager Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if(_cacheManager==null)
                    _cacheManager=new MemoryCacheManager();
                return _cacheManager;
            }
        }

        public object myObject { get; private set; }

    }
```

for resolve this problem and move to cache level in project you must use singleton pattern
but better solution for enterprise application use cache server like Ncache or appfabric